# Very long repairs with many out of sync ranges

Tags: cassandra

We're experiencing long repairs (9 to 14 hours) on our cluster (currently 2Tb of used data split on 3 nodes * 3 datacenters).

We're running full repairs daily (had some trouble with -pr at some point and never came back to it), and the logs show that most of the time is spent on compacting large rows (we will work on that soon) and also on syncing out of sync ranges.

As an example I have a CF that sometimes gets > 7K ranges out of sync, sometimes it's a rollup table from OpsCenter that's in the same situation (my CF is getting a lot of inserts and uses TTLs). Also, `nodetool tpstats` shows no dropped messages.

We are using Cassandra 1.2.11 (I know the latest is 1.2.13 but bugs concerning repair performance like CASSANDRA-4905 were fixed in 1.2.0).

So I would be interested by any suggestion on why we end up with so many out of sync ranges. From the way I understand Cassandra, even a write with a CL < ALL writes to all nodes, and only a dropped message would create an inconsistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repair performs no locking, so it's totally normal for large partitions (like opscenter's) to be out of sync at any given point in time.

Daily repair is probably overkill since [hinted handoff will take care of temporary availability hiccups](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/modern-hinted-handoff).

Comment: So the "out of sync" ranges are just ranges that are being written into at the moment of the repair ? I'm surprised that many transfers are initiated because of that (especially since the load is not that high during repair time). I guess I could focus on the long rows instead, does 10 hours for 2Tb sound right for you ?